# Iterating over dict of dicts vs (some other data structure) of dicts

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary

I'm looking at a codebase, and I see them iterating over only the values of a dict of dicts `d`. The only places where `d` is used, it's used with `itervalues()` (the code iterates over only the values of the dict), so the keys of `d` is never used, so I think they're just using the outer dict to hold all the inner dicts.

Is there an advantage to iterating values of a dict as opposed to just storing the dicts in a sequential data structure like a numpy array or a list, which might be more performant? I think especially with an array we can take advantage of cache locality?

Comment: It's up to a design intentions. Are the keys of the outer dict meaningful? Are they encountered anywhere during system's lifecycle?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest upon digging further, it seems the outer dict keys were useful when constructing the dict of dicts. but after it's constructed, it's only accessed through `itervalues()` so the keys are never used after construction

Comment: Wait, `itervalues`... are you using Python 2? Don't use Python 2. In recent Python versions, the entries of a dict are actually stored sequentially, so iteration is pretty fast (this is how insertion order is maintained)

Comment: Note, the only way you can store a dict in a numpy array is using the `object` dtype, which essentially makes your numpy array a less-useful python list.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm working with legacy code unfortunately

Comment: anyway, no, there is no good reason to store objects in a dict if you are only going to iterate over the values. Why this happened in the code base is not clear. Maybe whoever wrote the code thought that the dict would be used as a dict (i.e. as a mapping), or maybe it was, and that part was changed, but this part was kept.

Answer (score 0):

As RomanPerekhrest mentioned, dict-of-dicts helps avoid duplication if the outer dict key is expected to be uuique.
As for perf of iteration, no much difference from my python3 sample code:

```py
import timeit


setup_1 = ''' 
li_of_d = [{1:2} for _ in range(100)]
'''

setup_2 = ''' 
d_of_d = {i: {1:2} for i in range(100)}
'''

code_list_of_dicts = ''' 
x = 0
for d in li_of_d:
    x += d[1]
'''

code_dict_of_dicts = ''' 
x = 0
for d in d_of_d.values():
    x += d[1]
'''


print(timeit.repeat(stmt=code_list_of_dicts, setup=setup_1))
print(timeit.repeat(stmt=code_dict_of_dicts, setup=setup_2))
```

The result:

> [1.9167075000004843, 1.938053417019546, 1.9346700001042336, 1.9243456668918952, 1.9377128339838237]
> [2.0835109999170527, 2.077062583062798, 2.079794125049375, 2.097927958937362, 2.1154295000014827]

Maybe python2 behaves differently. But in general I don't think dict help iteration be faster. So maybe keep the legacy as if works for now.

For memory locality you mentioned (you said cache locality though), since both approaches are dealing with references of objects, memory locality is not so helpful.

Python list is AFAIK in CPython is dynamic array. So the references of our inner dict are stored continuously together.

Dict is also "kind of" continuous in memory in fact. It maps key to reference of value (ie, the reference of inner dict) by hashing plus collision resolution. There must be a data structure keeping eyes on all the occupied slots, otherwise no-way for itervalues(). I strongly guess that will be a list.

The references of inner dict all sit in a bounded interval of memory. Although not strictly continuous, they are not jumping all around among the whole memory space accessible for this program process. BTW when load factor reaches something like 66.6% or 75%. It will expand the memory space reserved to keep it sparse enough.

And these are all in RAM memory. In virtual memory space. And not L2 cache. Not disk.